Hidden Xcode folders on macOS 14.4.1

Mac Mini M1 2TB 16GB
macOS 14.4.1
Xcode 15.3

I've noticed that in my /Applications folder, I have a number of hidden items. These are:

As you can see, they are taking up a fair chunk of my disk space. Also, the presence of the term "replaced" in each of the filenames would suggest that they could be deleted without causing any harm.
Thoughts, anyone?

What exactly do we see in that screenshot? It does not look like the Finder.

No! The screenshot is from CleanMyMac (I decided to give it anther cautious try!). As for Finder, I'm a fan of QSpace Pro, which gives up to a four pane display!

I am not familiar with QSpace Pro, but since those files have “qspace” in their names I would guess that they were created by that application.

FWIW, I have Xcode installed and don't have those hidden items in /Applications.
Of course, if you have a backup, you can delete anything with impunity!
At most, you could also delete Xcode itself and re-download it.
